# Javascript Insert Function "arrayName.insert(item, function)"?

Tags: javascript, express

I am puzzled as to where or how the below function call for .insert() works? I've tried googling for javascript insert functions and looked through the entire directory for a defined insert function but there's nothing. Here is the code:

```
router.post('/new', function(req, res) {
    var username = req.session.username;
    var nextNote, note;

    var reportInserted = function(err, notesInserted) {
    if (err) {
        res.redirect("/notes?error=Could not create a new note");
    } else {
        res.redirect("/edit/" + notesInserted[0]._id);
    }
    }

    if (username) {
    newNote = {title: "Untitled",
           owner: username,
           content: "No content"};

    notesCollection.insert(newNote, reportInserted);
    } else {
    res.redirect("/?error=Not Logged In");
    }
});
```

Comment: (Much) more context is needed. Probably from a source file outside of the one you're looking at. It's very easy in JavaScript to define custom function properties on an Object, from scratch or by extending built-in objects. Presumably this was done here. The current directory is not authoritative. This looks like a Node.js snippet. You need to reference the controlling code and track down *everything* including all loaded modules (`require`).

Comment: I see you've added more but the key question of `notesCollection` is still rather context-less. You'll have it to trace it back to its very first declaration and initialization, which may infer tracing deeper through init functions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going out on a limb, and downvote me if you have to, but if you have no familiarity with what you see and it's not in the current directory, it's part of a pre-existing Node module. Idiomatically, chances are much better than 50-50 that it is:

http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html

The function right below the constructor is indeed `insert` and MongoDB is a very reasonable tool for a collection of notes, given that it's a document-oriented dynamic database.

Comment: I am curious if this guess was correct...let us know.